# Table staff in my phpmyadmin doesn't allow me to enter the employee identification card no

Tags: php, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

So, I've been asked by my employer to develop an attendance system if they attend a meeting where employees will only need to key in their ID_NO into the system. My problem is, when I was inserting their ID no, my staff table keep appearing like this

[image: the error produced]

and when I use query, it end up filling the ic_no with the number 2147483647
I really need the help to solve this since I need to proceed with the coding of the project next.

Comment: You should have Google'd that number. It would have more than likely avoided the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably go with BIGINT.

Take a look at the ranges:

```
+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
|  Type  |    Minimum Value     |    Maximum Value    |
+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
| INT    |          -2147483648 |          2147483647 |
| BIGINT | -9223372036854775808 | 9223372036854775807 |
+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Reference: [Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

Keep reading for more in-depth information...

---

## Why does it set that value?

> [...] When an out-of-range value is assigned to an integer column, MySQL
> stores the value representing the corresponding endpoint of the column
> data type range.

Ref: [Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html)

---

## Why didn't INT(15) work?

That number (15) doesn't share the same meaning as we have in VARCHAR.

> MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display
> width of integer data types [...]. The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column.

Ref: [Numeric Type Attributes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)